# PHP attachment in write form

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, upload

I need to edit the following form so it will have attach file function:

```
function _getWriteForm()
{
    $aForm = array(
        'form_attrs' => array(
            'name' => 'WallPostText',
            'action' => BX_DOL_URL_ROOT . $this->_oConfig->getBaseUri() . 'post/',
            'method' => 'post',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
            'target' => 'WallPostIframe',
            'onsubmit' => 'javascript:return ' . $this->_sJsPostObject . '.postSubmit(this);'
        ),
        'inputs' => array(
            'content' => array(
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'name' => 'content',
                'caption' => '',
                'colspan' => true
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'name' => 'submit',
                'value' => _t('_wall_post'),
                'colspan' => true
            )
        ),
    );
```

I wanted to edit HTML file first, but the only HTML code for this is:

```
<!-- Post Text -->
<div class="wall-ptype-cnt wall_text">__post_wall_text__</div>
```

Can someone please help me with editing array to allow file attachment?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
function _getWriteForm()
{
$aForm = array(
    'form_attrs' => array(
        'name' => 'WallPostText',
        'action' => BX_DOL_URL_ROOT . $this->_oConfig->getBaseUri() . 'post/',
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        'target' => 'WallPostIframe',
        'onsubmit' => 'javascript:return ' . $this->_sJsPostObject . '.postSubmit(this);'
    ),
    'inputs' => array(
        'content' => array(
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'name' => 'content',
            'caption' => '',
            'colspan' => true
        ),
         'file' => array(
            'type' => 'file',
            'name' => 'upload_file',
            'caption' => 'Upload',
            'colspan' => true
        ),
        'file_two' => array(    //I added a second input file
            'type' => 'file',
            'name' => 'upload_file_two',
            'caption' => 'Upload',
            'colspan' => true
        ),
        'submit' => array(
            'type' => 'submit',
            'name' => 'submit',
            'value' => _t('_wall_post'),
            'colspan' => true
        )
    ),
);
```

I hope it helps.

Saludos ;)

Comment: Thanks alot, it does work yes, but can this upload be multiple? because it only allows to choose 1 file upload. Sorry I did not mention that in my question.

Comment: Yes....it can be multiple.....you should simple duplicate the file array, like file1, file2 and like that....just simple copy paste ;)....i'm editing my answer ....wait

Comment: Lot`s of thanks to you again Robert, it really worked and is very useful for me in my future work as well:)